# How do you make an infinite printing loop in python?

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I'm new to python, and don't know much about loops. How would I make an infinite printing loop?

Comment: `while True: print(x)` Don't do that though.

Comment: I'd leave it at just "Don't do that."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This question is going to get closed lol, let the OP have some fun ;)

Comment: Well, there are reasons you might want to do that—say `x` is an expression that takes 3 seconds to calculate, and you want it to keep printing a value every 3 seconds until you hit Ctrl-C or the other side closes the pipe or whatever… But I doubt the OP has one of those reasons.

Comment: just a guess, I think OP might want infinite loop printing with **time interval** between each print, and he didn't know how to describe it in question

Comment: Or maybe he's just testing whether Python is faster than his terminal's stdout (which can be an interesting test with Windows cmd.exe or Cygwin terminals). :)

Comment: @abarnert True, but as of now, the question isn't detailed enough to make assumptions, and it doesn't really show any research effort. A simple Google search could answer it.

Comment: @logic: Sure; as I said "I doubt the OP has one of those reasons". If he does, it's up to him to tell us what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
while True:
    print("Whatever you want to print")
```

This is not suggested though, because it will leave your program running forever and that is not good.